# Grid of 3d boxes (only two faces)

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transforms

I have a grid of 3d boxes with only two faces (front and bottom). Each box has its own perspective. On hover, box rotates; bottom face faces the front. For example:

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.box-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box .face.front {
    transform: translateZ(123.5px);
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box .face.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(123.5px);
    background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem with this setup is the overlaps among boxes. I can get rid of the overlaps manually, and to do that I need to do following changes/calculations:

- change the `width`, `height`, and `margin`s (right and bottom) of the `.box-wrapper`
- change the `transform` (`translateZ`) of the `.face.front` and the `.face.bottom`

and since one change affects the others, this is problematic.

For example, to get rid of the overlaps in the setup above (1000px container), it requires the following changes:

```
.box-wrapper {
    width: calc(25% - 29px); // why 29?
    margin-right: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 29px;
    height: 221px;
}
.box .face.front {
    transform: translateZ(110.5px); // half of box's width
}
.box .face.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(110.5px);
}
```

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.box-wrapper {
    width: calc(25% - 29px);
    margin-right: 29px;
    margin-bottom: 29px;
    height: 221px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.box .face.front {
    transform: translateZ(110.5px);
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box .face.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(110.5px);
    background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also plan to make this mobile friendly, so as the window width changes, I'll change the width of the container (`.grid`), and do the above-mentioned changes. So the only variables I have are the container width which will change with respect to window width, and that a box should occupy 25% of the container width. How can I do this calculation automatically? Since the calculation includes perspective and transforms, I can't come up with anything yet.

Even if I calculate the values (width, margin, transform) manually (trial-error) for large screen breakpoints, at some point I need to do it automatically with JS, for example below 768px.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the issue comes from the `translateZ` combined with perspective. You are making your element closer to you with positive translation and the perspective is creating the overlap.

In order to avoid this we can need avoid the `translateZ` and use another configuration to create a similar effect. Here is an idea:

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.box-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .5s, transform-origin 0.5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.box .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box .face.front {
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box .face.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%) translateZ(125px);
    background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: rotateX(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    transform-origin:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, there is no more `translateZ` with the front element so no more overlap initially then I adjust the `transform-origin` and translation in order to compensate the `translateZ` applied to the bottom element.

All the values use are relative ones using percentage, so you won't have any issue doing calculation. I also added `box-sizing:border-box` to include border in the height/width calculation so that you can use exactly use half the height (`250px / 2 = 125px`) within `translateZ`.

**UPDATE**

I added a transition to the `transform-origin` in order to have a rotation somehow from the center and not completely from the top.

**UPDATE 2**

As suggested in the comment we can also change `transform-orgin` to `center center -125px`

```css
.grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.box-wrapper {
    width: 25%;
    height: 250px;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform .5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-origin:center center -125px;
}
.box .face {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box .face.front {
    background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box .face.bottom {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateY(50%) translateZ(125px);
    background-color: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, .5);
}
.box:hover {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrapper">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="face front">front face</div>
            <div class="face bottom">bottom-face</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this solution, but (I'm nitpicking I guess) the rotation seems a bit off. The rotation in my example seems to be occuring right at the center of the cube. In your example, watch the bottom of the cube, it doesn't overflow to the bottom (tiny few pixels), but the top overflows (a lot). This seems to give me an unrealistic look. Can this be fixed?

Comment: @akinuri yes and this is because the transform-origin that I changed ;) by default it occurs in the center but I made it to the top in order to fix the overlap ...  I will try to find another configuration in order to keep the rotation in the center ... but it won't be easy :p

Comment: Hah :) I'd really like it if it's fixable. Before your answer, I started experimenting: increasing translateZ step-by-step, note the change of width, try to map them and find a pattern... I gotta say, it's troublesome.

Comment: Set the `transform-origin` for `.box` and `.face` to `center center -125px`, the center of a 250px cube that's flush with the screen. Then you can drop the translate transforms.

Comment: @akinuri Yes I know it's not easy especially when you combine many transform over elements, you need a lot of imagination to understand how it works ... As a side note you may notice that transformZ only use pixel because it change in the z-axis while translateY/X can use % and the % is relative to width/height that's why they are useful for responsive.

Comment: @akinuri check the update it should be better now ... I added the transform origin on hover and added a transition to it .. so it will start from the center then it will get on top ;) you can play with delay and timing to adjust it

Comment: I see it slightly improved. Bottom overflows more, not as much as the top, but enough :) This will do for now. Although your answer is good, I'll keep the question open. I hope you don't mind. Someone might provide a mathematical JS solution (including translateZ), and I'm really interested in that.

Comment: @akinuri yes of course, don't accept too fast ;) by way, I gave you the mathematical solution :) .. using the combination of transform I avoided you the overflap and it was math ;) ... because what you actually want is to keep the same transform and then apply some math to other properties to fix the issue so better avoid it from the start :). Also you can play with transition of the transform-origin to improve more, you can change duration, adjust ease function, etc

Comment: I wanted to take a one last look at the demo and I can't believe I've missed `transform-origin: center center -125px;`. This solves the problem and gives the exact look that I want. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/0ce8fnx5/). You should update your demo.

Comment: @akinuri yes right, we can also do this ... But i wanted to avoid the use of pixel value as much as possible, as you can see now you have used 125px twice, but if you are ok with it, the you can do it ;)

Comment: @akinuri I have update to include you demo also, now we have more ways :)

Comment: Pixel values are fine, because I have to use them on small screens anyway (with JS). I might as well use them initially because they just seem to work. Not picky about that one :)